# Autocorrect spelling mistakes in text input

Tags: c#, algorithm, nlp, autocorrect

I am writing a natural language processor in C# that extracts the sentiment (positive/negative) of a sentence.  There is something of an issue, though, in being able to discern the sentiment of a misspelled word - if it's not in the dictionary, I can neither tag it nor rate it!

I know there has to be a way to handle this.  Google gives accurate suggestions all the time, I simply need to take the top suggestion from a similar algorithm and hit the database with it.  The problem is, I'm not sure where to start with algorithm names and so forth.  I need help figuring that out.

I checked around on the site for similar questions, and found some concepts that seemed useful, but the basic way of handling the distance between a misspelling and a real word basically relied on hitting every word in your data set, which seems horribly inefficient.  Some help with ideas to make the algorithm run quickly would also be much appreciated; this analysis engine is supposed to be able to handle multiple thousands of items a day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could hook in to google's API to do this for you. It's likely to give better results than most library solutions. You have to deal with the 200ms round trip time though, which isn't ideal.

Comment: You can cache the results and build a local dictionary

Comment: @Oliver, mind linking an article on how to do that, preferably in its own answer?  I agree it's not really the ideal situation but by the same token when something already works as well as Google's mechanics I'd be kind of silly to not consider it!

Comment: @YYY, Sorry, it looks like I am a bit behind the times. Google shut down their spelling API a year or so ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is not that stupid. Norvig wrote an [article](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) about it. Generally speaking the difficulty depends on the accuracy. The "easiest" way to do it is using a *prefix tree* or *trie* to avoid exploring all possibilities.
Basically you have something like this:

[image]

and following the path you basically stay on track. Once you reach a point where you are stuck you should check how to move on based on the type of error you have.

You can read Norvig's article for a deeper analysis.

Comment: What if the first letter of the word is spelt wrong and the rest is correct? I'm not sure a prefix tree is a good solution here. The Norvig article is a good read through.

Comment: I did not say it is the best solution. But imho it could work, even if you have a problem at the first letter, the kind of errors you have is basically the same, the problem is you're using the entire tree as space of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The approach given by dierre - including Peter Norvig's Article - is certainly worth being considered further.

However, for a quick-and-dirty solution: if a possibly misspelled word is not found in your own dictionary, you can try to find a mapping in this [list of common misspellings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aLists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines)

Answer (score 1):

The prefix trees mentioned by @dierre are extremely useful if you want to efficiently calculate the edit distance between a misspelling and a large set of dictionary words.  Brill and Moore (2000) describe an approach using prefix trees using the same general approach as Norvig and many other spell checkers.  Their paper is available here: http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/acl/P/P00/P00-1037.pdf